# Positioning a line with text between two divs

Tags: html, css

I've been redesigning a calculator for my website and there's a feature that I'd like to add to it. I have two divs next to each other and another div that I'd like to put in between them. I've been using the float function but nothing obvious seems to work. Aside from that, the div is supposed to contain two lines over and under text (I'll elaborate a bit more later) and I'm not sure what to do to achieve this, can someone please help?

Below is an image of what my issue is (red boxes are just to show the divs).

[image: Issue]

Below is what I'm trying to achieve (red boxes are just showing each div - not actually part of the design).
I want a line above and below "OR" that separates the divs on either side and it has to resize relative to the size of the whole thing. For example: if the window is resized (if that makes sense).

[image: Goal]

If you need additional information then please ask.

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you to use float since it has a strange behaviour sometimes. I would rather use flexboxes to achieve the layout.

**1. Create the HTML Structure:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left">
    
   </div>

   <div class="middle">
     
   </div>

   <div class="right">
     
   </div>
</div>
```

**2. Use CSS to create the layout:**

Alternativly you could use space-between, instead of space-around. This will change the horizontal layout a bit. An optinal feature would be vertical alignment, which can be edited with align-items like below.

```
.wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
}
```

If you want to learn more about flexboxes, take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Sheers!

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that flexboxes were a thing. That fixed the arrangement problem and I've found out how to do the line with text in the centre.

Comment: Glad to hear! Yes, flexboxes are very powerful! It's very easy to create responsive websites with them. Also, feel free to upvote my answer and mark it as helpful. Sheers and good luck!